# How to get an element within ArrayList in java

Tags: java, list

I want to insert a csv file content to a list .

```
col1,col2,col3
b,a,v
a,c,p
d,a,z
q,z,a
r,a,b
```

So that I can get  a specific `col` value

for example : if 2 nd col then

```
a
c
a
z
a
```

I tried to insert it into a list

```
list: [b,a,v, a,c,p, d,a,z, q,z,a, r,a,b]
```

But how will I get the 2nd col value.

**UPDATE**

```
 ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 ar.add(line);
 System.out.println("list: "+ar);
```

I am able to print first index.

using

```
System.out.println("get index: "+ar.get(0));
get index: b,a,v
```

but i need to get 'a' ie need all 2 nd column of the given data

Comment: can we see some code?

Comment: A single list is unlikely to be the correct data structure. Perhaps a list of lists will work.

Comment: well.. An ArrayList of Arraylists could help you...

Comment: If you know the number of columns (three in this case), and the position of the elements never changes (i.e. you never modify the list) then you could calculate the required indexes for your 2nd column values easily enough. You're better off using a data structure that preserves the row/column structure (a list of lists, as others have said) instead though.

Comment: Array list is not for storing multidimensional data. It is primarily for storing single column of data.

Comment: I got the answer and i accepted. Pls remove the hold. I am not able to ask questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your update, You need *a* from *b,a,v* . Here you can split the string and get the middle element i.e index 1 element. So following code snippet will get the 2nd value in each element and print it

```
for(int i=0;i<ar.size();i++) {
            String[] tokens=(ar.get(i)).split(",");
            System.out.println(tokens[1]);
        }
```

With out using indexes of arraylist, You can use for each loop

```
for(String value:ar) {
            String[] tokens=value.split(",");
            System.out.println(tokens[1]);

        }
```

Comment: But how to get all the lists 2 nd value.without giving it as static to 0

Comment: @Sree put the statements in loop and print them

Comment: @Sree - Updated the code to get all the 2nd values in each element

Comment: @Sree - Hope your issue is resolved, If so please accept the answer

Comment: thanks gowtham :) I accepted ur answer

Comment: how to make tokens[1] dynamic?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45426/discussion-between-gowtham-and-sree)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1** 
Instead of list use List.so your list become

```
List<List>: [ [b,a,v], [a,c,p], [d,a,z], [q,z,a], [r,a,b]]
```

And to get any row you just have to call

```
List<List<String> list;

List<String> row = list.get(index);     \\will return you corresponding row
String content = row.get(1);            \\will return col2 value
```

**Solution 2** 
if you go by single list then to get any element you must have to perform some calculation like

```
list<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
ar.get(row * 3 + column)     // will return you column of row you want.
```

*Note: row and column count starts from 0 not 1*

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop will provide a trick,
Assign `i` with the initial value of `columnnumber - 1`, where `columnnumber` is the column value you are looking for,

```
for (int i = columnnumber - 1; i < args.length; i+=3) 
{
    System.out.print(args[i] + ", ");

}
```

Since each row contains 3 values and you have created a single list.

Answer (score 1):

List is 0 index based. Index 1 will return the 2nd element from the list.

Use like this.

```
list.get(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
ArrayList list = ... ;

...

int colId = 1;
int numCols = 3;

for(int i = colId; i < list.size(); i += numCols){
  System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%` operator if you are having only `ArrayList`.

Logic goes like this :

```
int colNo = 3 ; // column no which you want to get from list

for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
     if ( i % colNo == 0) {
         System.out.println(list.get(i));
     }
}
```

However in your case it is recommended to use list of list.